# Rails Active Record query against just the date field of the created_at datetime value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to return some records from my "counts" table.

How do I get just the date portion of the created_at field, using date(created_at) as below doesn't work.

```
Count.where(channel_id: channel_id)
     .where(date(created_at:) :date Date.yesterday)
     .followers
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Simon

Comment: what is the RDMS you are using? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

Comment: postgresSQL is the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple trick is to use a `BETWEEN` clause, achievable without writing pure SQL and just by using ActiveRecord:

```
Count
  .where(channel_id: channel_id)
  .where(created_at: Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day..Date.yesterday.end_of_day)
```

It will translate to the following SQL:

```
WHERE ("counts"."created_at" BETWEEN '2019-01-02 00:00:00.000000' AND '2019-01-02 23:59:59.999999')
```

Comment: This worked for me and my final working solution was:
    Count.where(created_at: Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day..Date.yesterday.end_of_day).first.followers

and i think is a nice solution.

Comment: spoke to soon, the AND statement is missing so the channel_id check doesnt work now?

Comment: @Simonp27 I just updated my answer to add the where clause on the `channel_id`